# Subscription OG Group

Tags: organic-groups, notifications

I want that user can subscribe to content add in several OG GROUP.

How can achieve that ?

Cordially

Answer (score 0):

Yes, By default `og_group_ref` field  (organic group field machine name by default  add to your content types) accept multi value, if  for you it's **Number of values** set `1` value, go to you `content type manage fields` and change it to `unlimited` value